# Jersey Rest Returning 400 for file upload/multipart

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

**Test Case** Using this test case to upload file and form data

```
    final Client client =     ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget t = client.target("http://localhost:8080/context/dnt/post").path("upload2");

    PostTestCases postTestCases=new PostTestCases();
    String file1=postTestCases.getFileName("images/ny.jpeg");
    String file2=postTestCases.getFileName("images/sf.jpeg");

    FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("files", new File(file1));
    filePart.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("files").fileName("ny.jpeg").build());

    FileDataBodyPart filePart1 = new FileDataBodyPart("files", new File(file2));
    filePart1.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("files").fileName("sf.jpeg").build());

    PostDTO post = populatePostDTO();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(post);

    MultiPart multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart().field("postDTO", value, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .bodyPart(filePart).bodyPart(filePart1);

    Response response = t.request().post(Entity.entity(multipartEntity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));

    response.close();
```

**Response:** Response from test case

```
INFO: 2 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-4
2 > POST http://localhost:8080/context/dnt/post/upload2
2 > accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
2 > connection: keep-alive
2 > content-length: 19855
2 > content-type: multipart/form-      data;boundary=Boundary_1_1326393666_1485290224667
2 > host: localhost:8080
2 > mime-version: 1.0
2 > user-agent: Jersey/2.25 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_77)

Jan 24, 2017 3:37:04 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-4
2 < 400
```

**Method :**  This is method I am using to accept the image and data

```
   @POST
   @Path("/upload2")
   @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
   public Response uploadFileWithData(
        @FormDataParam("files") List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts,
        @FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition fileDispositions,
        @FormDataParam("postDTO") PostDTO postDTO) throws Exception{


    Post post = mapper.map(postDTO, Post.class);
    postService.createPost(bodyParts,post);

    return Response.ok("Cool Tools!").build();
```

**Adding Images from Rest Client**
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc7ho.jpg)

I have tried adding jersey-multipart-config.properties but still giving me 400 bad request.